# Changing system date & time in OpenSuse 11.1

Tags: linux, opensuse, time

Opensuse 11.1 date command shows:

```
# date
Wed Dec 23 11:43:27 EST 2009
```

And I want to change it to current date i.e. **July 29 00:50:12 2009**. The command I am using to do that is

```
# date -s "29 July 2009 00:50:12"
Wed July 29 00:50:12 EDT 2009
```

But as I issue date command, it reverts back to the old value with timezone as *EST* rather than *EDT*

```
# date
Wed Dec 23 11:45:30 EST 2009
```

Moreover, I could not synchronize *HWClock* because its giving me following error

```
# hwclock --debug
hwclock from util-linux-2.12r
hwclock: Open of /dev/rtc failed, errno=19: No such device.
No usable clock interface found.
Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
```

The timezone is correctly set in */etc/sysconfig/clock*

```
HWCLOCK="-u"

SYSTOHC="yes"

TIMEZONE="US/Eastern"
DEFAULT_TIMEZONE="US/Eastern"
```

I don't think there is any NTP server configured as well */etc/ntp.conf*

```
server 127.127.1.0
fudge 127.127.1.0  stratum 10
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift/ntp.drift
logfile /var/log/ntp

server 0.pool.ntp.org
server 1.pool.ntp.org
server 2.pool.ntp.org
```

The problem is I've to do everything via shell and also without YaST & YaST2.
Please advice

> ### Edit
>
> sysadmin1138: Thanks.
>      I started the *rcntp*.
>
> ```
> # rcntp start
> Try to get initial date and time via NTP from 0.pool.ntp.org 1.pool.ntdoneg 2.pool.ntp.org  
> Starting network time protocol daemon (NTPD)                         done  
> # date  
> Wed Dec 23 13:05:24 EST 2009
> ```
>
> Also I have used the *ntpdate*
>
> ```
> # ntpdate 0.pool.ntp.org  
> 23 Dec 13:04:01 ntpdate[16408]: step time server 209.123.234.24 offset -12744325.660513 sec
> ```
>
> But still the issue has not resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your NTP service is configured, but you haven't said if it is turned on. The command to see if NTP is turned on is "rcntp status" and will give you rather clear indication if it is turned on or not.

```
 Checking for network time protocol daemon (NTPD):                    running
```

Starting it once is as simple as "rcntp start".

Another possible route if ntp is not up is to use the 'ntpdate' command.

```
 ntpdate 0.pool.ntp.org
```

That will set the local clock per what that NTP server says. What your 'date' command returns at that point will be diagnostic of further errors. On the other hand, if it is correct, then turning NTP on as a service should keep this server with correct time.

Answer (score 0):

To change the date under Linux you should be Su the write the following:

```
date mmddhhmmyy
```

This for date. For ntp you can check it from yast2. In a xterminal with root permissions (`su -`) run the tool `yast2`. Then go to ntp server\clinet configuration.